# Unity 5 networking color sync

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to sync my cube's color from my server script. I have Network Transform  and Network Identity component on it and transform synchronizing works good, now I'd need to sync the color. I need something like Network Material component or how else should I do this? Thank you :) (I hope you got what i mean, sorry for english.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sync values using the SyncVar attribute:

```
[SyncVar]
Color myColor;
```

This will keep the changes syncronized on clients and the server. But this is just a field in your class of color type, it doesn't actually change the color of your render.

You could change the color of your render to your `myColor` value in the Update callback, but it would update it even when there is no change in the color.

The best approach would be using a hook:

```
[SyncVar (hook = "OnColorChanged")]
Color myColor;
```

This will call the "OnColorChanged" function each time the color is updated.

Something like this should work (if you are working with SpriteRenders):

```
[SyncVar (hook = "OnColorChanged")]
Color myColor;

void OnColorChanged(Color value)
{
    myColor = value;
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = myColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so I have added this code into my Client and Network script, but I'm getting this error now: UNetWeaver error: Script UnityEngine.Networking.ConnectClient uses [SyncVar] myColor but is not a NetworkBehaviour.

Comment: When declaring the Class, it usually derives from MonoBehaviour, but for SyncVar to work it must derive from NetworkBehaviour. Change the class declaration from `public Class myClass : MonoBehaviour` to `public Class myClass : NetworkBehaviour`

Comment: Thank you, changing MonoBehaviour to Network solved the error. But my cube doesn't change its color. My code: http://pastebin.com/TAStVciy

Comment: The code I mentioned shouldn't be on the NetworkManager, but in the script assigned to your cube, which should be a network identity.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much for your help :) I will accept you answer.